# Single pair ethernet (SPE) PHY with ESP32

Tags: ethernet, phy

can I connect this Single Pair Ethernet PHY http://www.ti.com/product/DP83TC811R-Q1 to a ESP32 chip? Do I miss something?

Does anyone already know a Switch for Single Pair Ethernet?

Looking forward to your input.

Comment: Why do you need to connect an Ethernet module to a WiFi module?

Comment: It is not possible to always have WiFi there and the device also needs power. So SPE would be ideal.

Comment: @EugeneSh. WiFi access points (AP, bridges) do that. Although maybe not with SPE. But who knows...

Answer (score 1):

> Can I connect this Single Pair Ethernet PHY DP83TC811R-Q1 to a ESP32 chip?

NO.

The DP83TC811R-Q1 is a PHY implementation, and it connects to a MAC implementation driven by an Ethernet controller. To support this chip on an ESP32 would require that you select a MAC chip and connect that to the PHY.....but beyond that you need an Ethernet controller to build the protocol packets to be serialized.

[image]

Comment: But I thought that the ESP32 exactly has that MAC implementation and an ethernet controller? Page 24 in the datasheet: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf

Comment: If you are laying out your own PCB for an ESP32 chip, then yes, the connections are available….but none of the ESP8266 boards that I know of have the pins available. Most problematic is GPIO0 which is used during programming. The boards that support Ethernet already have a PHY built on the board such as the Expressif ESP32-POE, ESP32-Gateway and ESP32-EVB.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I would make my own PCB. So I have to find the right ESP32 chip with the pinout to support Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to.
but the driver is not part of the espresif SDK. you should wryte your own.

100-base T1 and 1000 base T1, is very specific mainly for automotive. In my knowledge you ave no switch on the market at low price.

Also T1 is limited to 15 meter long. if you want to dig in take a look on the Podl ( power on data line). it's a POE on single pair ethernet.